# Spring boot war deployment fails to initialize with same configuration on diff machines

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using the 'getting-started' example of Spring Boot and trying to deploy it as a war on tomcat version 8.0.28. I am using Maven, which is creating the war for me and I am copying it directly into webapps folder. On one machine, I get the following log -

a

```
rtInternal Starting service Catalina
04-Nov-2015 00:47:41.667 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.sta
rtInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
04-Nov-2015 00:47:41.688 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
\webapps\gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.war
04-Nov-2015 00:47:43.114 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.
TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.
 Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scan
ned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can i
mprove startup time and JSP compilation time.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.7.RELEASE)
```

the **same war,** using the **same tomcat version** on a different machine, gives me this log -

```
04-Nov-2015 00:35:39.289 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-t
omcat-8.0.28\webapps\ROOT has finished in 26 ms
04-Nov-2015 00:35:39.297 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
arting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-80"]
04-Nov-2015 00:35:39.306 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start St
arting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
04-Nov-2015 00:35:39.308 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start
Server startup in 8431 ms
04-Nov-2015 00:45:00.169 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catal
ina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/gs-
spring-boot-0.1.0]
04-Nov-2015 00:45:51.015 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.28
\webapps\gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.war
04-Nov-2015 00:45:53.417 INFO [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startu
p.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\apache-tomcat-8.
0.28\webapps\gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.war has finished in 2,403 ms
```

This doesn't make any sense. What could be going wrong??

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found out why this is happening, but I am not sure about the root cause. On the machine where Spring Boot was not getting initiated, the JRE version was 7.0 and on the machine where it was working just fine, the JRE version was 8.0. I upgraded the JRE and it started working.

I thought Tomcat 8 should initialize Spring Boot App in war since this is supported by Servlet 3.0 specification. Anyway, if anyone knows the root cause, please go ahead and add an answer.

Comment: Was your app compiled with Java 7 or Java 8? I wonder if it could be poor diagnostics from Tomcat when it's running on Java 7 and can't make sense of the Java 8 bytecode.

Comment: yes, it was compiled on Java 8, but Tomcat did not complain about it - You are correct, it should have just thrown a version incompatibility error.